# domain of exponential map for a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. I'm supposed to show that for any fixed $p\in M$, the exponential map $\text{exp}_p:T_pM \rightarrow M$ is defined on all of $T_p$. 
So far I have:

- By Hopf Rinow, since $M$ is complete as a metric space, it is also geodesically complete.
- the domain of $\text{exp}_p$ is star-shaped around zero, so I find a ball $B(\epsilon,p) \subset T_pM$ lying in that domain. Can I expand that domain via Hopf Rinow to get the entire space?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Aren't you done? The statement that you want to show is precisely that of  geodesically completness.

Comment: we defined geodesically completeness as "every maximal geodesic is defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$". but that's obviously the same isn't it? @JohnMa

Comment: @Simonsays: The difference of what you wrote with geodesic completeness is purely semantical.